# Getting up and running with basic scripting

Tags: extendscript, adobe-premiere

I am adopting Premier as my main editor, slowly transitioning from another editor that did not offer any scripting/programming access.

The whole reason I picked up Premier is that it offers scripting and a C++ SDK. This is something I will expand into slowly over time.

I have a programming background but am short on time, right now I really just want to invoke premier commands from an external source, such a PowerShell or AutoHotkey.

Simple tasks such as `Quick_Edit_SetUp.Jsx` that carries out sequential steps, such as:

1. Open  `C:\Temp\Quick_Edit.Jsx`
2. Import `C:\Users\smith\Videos\Todays_Feed2.mp4` into the `Project: Quick_Edit` Panel
3. Create a new sequence

   1. Import `C:\Users\smith\Videos\Todays_Feed2.mp4` and place it into the sequence

And another called `Quick_Edit_Exit.Jsx` that carries out sequential steps, such as:

1. Close Project without saving
2. Quit Premiere Process

I recently discovered that you can run arbitrary `.JSX` code from **PowerShell** like so:

```
PremierPro /C es.processFile "C:\TEMP\Test.jsx"        # Contents of Test.Jsx is ===>  alert("Hello, World");
```

But this requires that Premier also be launched at the same time, otherwise you end up getting the following error:

[image]

Is there no way to invoke `PremierPro /C es.processFile "C:\TEMP\Test.jsx"`  against an already running instance of Premier?
If the answer is "No", then what route do I need to take be able to achieve my goal of invoking premier commands from an external source, such a PowerShell or AutoHotkey?

I have scoured the docs and what third party help I can find. Some suggest `.Jsx` others say **ExtendScript**. Are they not the same thing? Is **ExtendScript** not just stored in `.Jsx` files?

Please, I would appreciate any input or articles that demystifies this for me.

Comment: Yes '.jsx' is the generally accepted extension for Adobe ExtendScript scripts. But you free to use any extension you want. In old days there was '.js' extension as well. But it can be confused with plain browser on Node.js Javascript files so it makes sene don't use it. As for the main problem, unfortunately I have no expertise in Premiere. I know how you can run Photoshop, InDesign, Illustrator from Python (on Windows). Most likely you can run Premier in the same way. Ultimately you can run Python from PowehShell. This chain will work somehow. Not sure if it's an optimal solution, though,

Comment: Here is several examples with Python + InDesign: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66674743/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60010609/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195622/ etc. If you have a knack for PowerShell perhaps you will be able to see some familiar patterns and use the win32com API directly from PowerShell.

Comment: @YuriKhristich, I see. I will go down the rat hole you propose and see what I find. Thanks mate.

Comment: @YuriKhristich, I recently discovered for certain that Premier is one of the few adobe software that does not run external `.Jsx` on demand. There is allot of set up that is needed before that, the commonly suggested routine is something called a "hidden panel". Some sort of custom panel created for the sole purpose of communicating with an external  process. One long headache to another it seems. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older toolchain [ExtendScript Toolkit](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/tree/master/ExtendScript-Toolkit) uses an existing instance of Premiere, rather than spawning a new one as you would with the CLI invokation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. If I am understanding you correctly, Installing this older Extend Script version then invoking the same Cli command would use an existing Premier instance? Does this mean I can use the latest Premier version, that I am forced to use by Adobe CC?

Comment: correct.  comments must be 15 characters in length.